# Click Event Coords Not the Same as Shape Location

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm really new to both the canvas and javascript. I was trying to make a button that did something when you click it.  When I created a click event for a button, I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Then, when I tried troubleshooting I discovered that the x,y coords of the rectangle shape was completely off compared to where the click event said I was clicking. I'm completely baffled.  I added some code just to make sure I wasn't insane.  The clicks are saying my coords begin a lot higher on the X axis despite being on the far left of the canvas.

The shape is at X = 565
The click says I'm at X = 1161

Here's my code:

```
function bigButton(x, y, strTxt)
{
    var getID = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

    if (getID.getContext)
    {
        var btnCtx = getID.getContext("2d");

        btnCtx.font = "Italic 32pt Times";
        btnCtx.textAlign = "center";
        btnCtx.textBaseline = "middle";

        var btnW = 150;
        var btnH = 50;
        var cx = x - btnW/2;
        var cy = y - btnH/2;
        var left = cx;
        var right = cx + btnW;
        var top = cy;
        var bottom = cy + btnH;

        btnCtx.strokeRect(cx, cy, btnW, btnH);
        btnCtx.fillText(strTxt, x, y);
        btnCtx.font = "24pt Helvetica";
        btnCtx.fillText("Coordinates of Rectangle: X = " + cx + " Y = " + cy, cx, cy + 90);

        getID.addEventListener("click", function(event)
        {
            var clickX = event.x;
            var clickY = event.y;
            alert(clickX + " " + clickY);

        }, false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client coordinates in the event are relative to client window. The `x` and `y` properties that you are currently using is not part of a [standard event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent) so they should be avoided in any case. Use `clientX/Y` or one of the others instead.

In order to make them relative to canvas you can simply subtract the canvas' absolute position.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
getID.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();  // get abs. region of canvas
    var clickX = event.clientX - rect.left;    // adjust x
    var clickY = event.clientY - rect.top;     // adjust y

    alert(clickX + " " + clickY);

}, false);
```

Also make sure you don't set the canvas size using CSS but it's `width` and `height` attributes (or properties if done in JS) as the bitmap will be scaled to the element size which also affects the mouse position (relative to the bitmap).

If you apply padding or border to the canvas they will affect the relative position as well. Do either:

1. Replace padding with margin (margin does not affect the client rect) and set `display: block;`
2. Wrap the canvas into a parent div element and apply the CSS rule to parent instead
3. Subtract border/padding top/left sizes in the formula

Comment: @Teemu yeah, I noticed. I'll make a note.

Comment: I tried this, with event.clientX/Y and it did put 0 at the top left corner of the canvas, however, it still thinks the rectangle is at 900 instead of 1164. So, closer, but not quite.  By the way, the x and y variables passed to the function are based on half the width and height of the canvas, so that the button would appear in the middle.

Comment: @Sephethus did you properly set the size of the canvas using the width/height attributes (not CSS) ? Padding and border will affect the client rect.

Comment: I used the .width and .height attributes for the canvas element using java, not CSS. However, I did use CSS for the border and padding, so I could put the canvas in the center of the page.

Comment: If I remove all the CSS and just keep the border it works. So apparently the problem is with the CSS. Now I have to figure out how I put the canvas in the middle of the page.

Comment: @Sephethus You can put the canvas in a parent div and apply the CSS to that instead.

Comment: I'll try that. Also just having display: block; and margin: 0 auto; worked as well, without messing up the x,y.

Comment: @Sephethus nice. I'll include those in the answer for future visitors